# List to Data Frame in R

Tags: r

I want to run an F-test using "Zelazo" in the "ISwR" package.

the data looks like:

```
$active
[1]  9.00  9.50  9.75 10.00 13.00  9.50

$passive
[1] 11.00 10.00 10.00 11.75 10.50 15.00

$none
[1] 11.50 12.00  9.00 11.50 13.25 13.00

$ctr.8w
[1] 13.25 11.50 12.00 13.50 11.50
```

What I need to do before running an F-Test is to make this usable for my purposes. That means making a 23x2 Data Frame (there are 23 "age" values and two categories, "age" and "method" with method being: "active", "passive", etc...)

I want:

```
"age" "method" 
9.00 active
9.5 active
.   .
.   .
.   .
11 passive
```

and so on..

What is the best way to go about that?

Comment: `stack(listname)`

Comment: Should I delete this question? Answer is good. Thanks!

Comment: If you like, doesn't matter too much as the duplicates are all linked now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to stick the two together into a table, you can consider using the `rbind` function.

I've compiled a simple example using number vectors, but broken it down into steps. You can always wrap a function within a function to save resources/time.

```
active <-  c(9.00,  9.50,  9.75, 10.00, 13.00,  9.50)
passive <- c(11.00, 10.00, 10.00, 11.75, 10.50, 15.00)

step1 <- data.frame(age=c(active), method='active')
step2 <- data.frame(age=c(passive), method='passive')
step3 <- data.frame(rbind(step1, step2))
```

What I'm essentially doing is creating two seperate `data.frame` elements and using the `rbind` function which basically performs a [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) if you're familiar with set theory.

> Note: For this function to work, columns must match.